# SQLAlchemy: How to perform multiple independent CTEs?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

I have working SQL code that have two CTE and one of them must work in parallel with main statement like that:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS (...get initial rows...),
cte2 AS (...select rows from cte1 and insert in table1 in parallel to main statement...)
INSERT INTO table2 (...) SELECT ... FROM cte1;
```

And I write code for all parts with help of SQLAlchemy:

```py
cte1 = select(...).cte('cte1', recursive=True)
cte2 = table1.insert().from_select([...], select(...here i use cte1...)).cte('cte2')
result = table2.insert().from_select([...], select(...here i use cte1 too...))
```

But I can not insert cte2 in my query because I do not use it in result statement and I can not find a way to include cte2 somehow else...
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: As there is still no answer after all these years I've posted the question as [an issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/6569) in sqlalchemy's github repository.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `cte2` `returning` part and then use in `result` query data from `cte2` `returning` instead of `cte1`